# Explain the notation for the Cartesian product of a family of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

In "Lattices and Ordered Sets" author S. Roman defines the Cartesian product of a family of sets. I understand the concept. What I don't understand however is the notation he has used. He says, "for this, we use functions". Now see the definition on the attached copy of a page from his book starting with $ \Pi \mathcal{F}.$ Please explain in detail what all of the notation means, what is the domain, the range? ( I got many duplicate question candidates about Cartesian product families but none answered my question ).

[image: page 1 Lattices and Ordered Sets]

Comment: $\prod\mathcal{F}$ means exactly the same as the other two symbols.

Comment: I am basically interested what is in between the brackets.

Comment: What isn't clear?

Comment: How it is a function, what maps to what? WHere does the f (i) come from.

Comment: The $ I \mapsto $ is confusing.

Comment: It's not how I would define a map, I would start by defining domain and range followed by the rule how we bring an element from domain to range.

Comment: It's not a function, but a set of functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20096/discussion-between-ndroock1-and-egreg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation
$$
\biggl\{ f\colon I\to \bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\biggm| f(i)\in X_i\biggr\}
$$
(there's an obvious typo, as $A_i$ should be $X_i$) denotes the set consisting of *all* functions having domain $I$ (the index set of the family $\mathcal{F}$) and codomain the union of the sets in the family $\mathcal{F}$ that satisfy the condition
$$
f(i)\in X_i
$$
*for all* $i\in I$ (the “for all” clause is also missing).

So, if $I=\{0,1\}$ and $X_0=\{a,b,c\}$, $X_1=\{c,d,e\}$, we should think to all functions
$$
f\colon \{0,1\}\to\{a,b,c,d,e\}
$$
such that $f(0)\in X_0$ and $f(1)\in X_1$. Thus
$$
\prod_{i\in\{0,1\}}X_i
$$
consists of the functions
\begin{align}
\Bigl\{&
  \{(0,a),(1,c)\},
  \{(0,a),(1,d)\},
  \{(0,a),(1,e)\},\\&
  \{(0,b),(1,c)\},
  \{(0,b),(1,d)\},
  \{(0,b),(1,e)\},\\&
  \{(0,c),(1,c)\},
  \{(0,c),(1,d)\},
  \{(0,c),(1,e)\}\Bigr\}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank G__ a typo, you made it much clearer,  thanks.

Comment: I am reading the same textbook, thank you for your clarifications! But I think you should use $((0,a),(1,c))$ instead of $\{(0,a),(1,c)\}$

Comment: @LawrenceGuo No: $\{(0,a),(1,c)\}$ is a set of ordered pairs (and a function with domain $\{0,1\}$), whereas $\bigl((0,a),(1,c)\bigr)$ is an ordered pair.

Comment: @egregwould you please explain why a arbitrary element of $\prod X_i$ would be a set of ordered tuple rather than a tuple. I reckon this definiton should be equivalent to that ordered pair definiton (e.b $A\times B=\{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$ ),  I thought ${(0,a),(1,c)} $ should corresponds to $(a,c)$ in ordered pair definiton.

Comment: @LawrenceGuo The product set is a set of functions.